# Изменить цвет текста в f строке

Tags: python

Когда я использую просто print, я могу изменить цвет вывода таким образом:

```
print('\033[1;35m text')
```

Можно ли то же самое как то сделать с f строкой, где print(f'цветной текст')? Если я помещаю \033.. внутрь, то оно просто печатается вместе с текстом.

Comment: Сделал `print(f'\033[1;35m цветной текст')` — получился цветной текст, всё работает

Comment: Это работает только в терминале, поддерживающем ansi последовательности. Терминал windows сам по себе такое не поддерживает. Можно установить модуль colorama, он умеет добавлять эмуляцию, в своей программе нужно его будет импортировать и инициализировать.